# Retrofit 2 RequestBody writeTo() method called twice

Tags: java, android, upload, retrofit2

Retrofit 2 RequestBody writeTo() method called twice, the code which I used is given below:

```
ProgressRequestBody requestVideoFile = new ProgressRequestBody(videoFile, new ProgressRequestBody.UploadCallbacks() {

    VideoUploadStore store = new VideoUploadStore();

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(int percentage) {
        if (!mIsCancelled) {
            Log.i("UploadServiceManager", "Read Percentage : " + percentage);
            data.setUploadPercentage(percentage);
            store.updateUploadData(data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
        if(!mIsCancelled) {
            data.setUploadPercentage(0);
            store.updateUploadData(data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }
});
MultipartBody.Part multipartVideo = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("File", videoFile.getName(), requestVideoFile);
```

Comment: Could you please state the question?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The solution below might help you out , although it might be too late. :p

Remove `HttpLoggingInterceptor` Object in your Api Client which will not execute writeTo() function twice.Basically , `HttpLoggingInterceptor`  loads the data buffer first ( for internal logging purpose ) by calling writeTo() and then again calls writeTo() for uploading the data to server.

```
  HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
  logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
  httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
```

Comment: I just commented my logging interceptor and it worked, thank you for the answer and for the explanation.

Comment: Great solution! After removing the HttpLoggingInterceptor code, dont use InstantRu. Run the app again to remove it.

Comment: I thought it was some of my interceptors but indeed, logging interceptor caused this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great solution! Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Nice and clean!

Answer (score 9):

If you're using `writeTo()` to track file upload progress, you need to distinguish between the callers of `writeTo()`. Basically `writeTo()` can be called by any interceptor in the chain, e.g. any logging interceptor such as a `HttpLoggingInterceptor`/`OkHttpProfilerInterceptor`/`StethoInterceptor`, and this method provides no context for that.

The simplest approach (as pointed out by other answers) is to get rid of those interceptors that require access to the request body. But this may be not always feasible.

Another solution is to make use of the fact that a server call is performed by a `CallServerInterceptor` which is the last interceptor in the chain (according to the docs). You can inspect stack trace prior to further handling. Yes, this is ugly. But this way you don't have to modify your interceptors or leave room for subtle bugs when someone else comes up and adds another interceptor.

```
override fun writeTo(sink: BufferedSink) {
    val isCalledByCallServerInterceptor = Thread.currentThread().stackTrace.any { stackTraceElement ->
        stackTraceElement.className == CallServerInterceptor::class.java.canonicalName
    }

    // TODO
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Decreasing log level from BODY to HEADERS, BASIC or NONE solved this problem for me

Answer (score 7):

I figured out yet another case for twice called writeTo() method.
I use OkHttpClient without Retrofit and HttpLoggingInterceptor, and I have the *twice called* problem.

**Solution**: the problem appears after upgrade Android Studio to 3.1.1 and enable Advanced Profiling in run project configuration. So disable Advanced Profiling.

Comment: Yet another cause for twice called writeTo() is using StethoInterceptor for capture traffic from OkHttp. You'll see that if you add network interceptor and open Stetho console.

Answer (score 0):

decreasing level from BODY to HEADERS and removing HttpLoggingInterceptor is not a solution for me because it gave explanation about what is going on with the api called. you can just initiate counter variable like,
`private int firstTimeCounter = 0;` then

```
@Override
public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
    firstTimeCounter += 1;

    .......
   .......

    if(firstTimeCounter==2){
        try {
            while (total != file.length()) {
                read = source.read(sink.buffer(), SEGMENT_SIZE);
                total += read;
                Log.e("progress ", total + " %");
                sink.flush();
            }
        } finally {
            okhttp3.internal.Util.closeQuietly(source);
        }
    }
}
```